# Why Magic Quotes has been removed from PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, magic-quotes

What are the technical reasons that `Magic Quotes` has been removed from PHP 5.4 ?

**From PHP docs**

## Performance

> Performance Because not every piece of escaped data is inserted into a database, there is a performance loss for escaping all this data. Simply calling on the escaping functions (like **addslashes()**) at runtime is more efficient. Although php.ini-development enables these directives by default, php.ini-production disables it. This recommendation is mainly due to performance reasons.

Is there any other reason why `Magic Quotes` has been removed from PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is very well explained why the deprecated in manual by [chao](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php#102907)

> Quoting comment of [**chao**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php#102907)
>
> The very reason magic quotes are deprecated is that a one-size-fits-all approach to escaping/quoting is wrongheaded and downright dangerous.  Different types of content have different special chars and different ways of escaping them, and what works in one tends to have side effects elsewhere.  Any sample code, here or anywhere else, that pretends to work like magic quotes --or does a similar conversion for HTML, SQL, or anything else for that matter -- is similarly wrongheaded and similarly dangerous.
>
> Magic quotes are not for security.  They never have been.  It's a convenience thing -- they exist so a PHP noob can fumble along and eventually write some mysql queries that kinda work, without having to learn about escaping/quoting data properly.  They prevent a few accidental syntax errors, as is their job.  But they won't stop a malicious and semi-knowledgeable attacker from trashing the PHP noob's database.  And that poor noob may never even know how or why his database is now gone, because magic quotes (or his spiffy "i'm gonna escape everything" function) gave him a false sense of security.  He never had to learn how to really handle untrusted input.

also good read [**Wikipedia : Magic quotes Criticism**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_quotes#Criticism)